# Merge multiple arrays with same indexes php

Tags: php

how can I get this :

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 3
 )  
  [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 2 
        [1] => 4
 )
)
```

from this :

```
$array1 = [1,2];
$array2 = [3,4];
```

So basically, just group arrays that share the same index, so 1- 3 would be in the same array and 2-4 in the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a couple of calls to `array_column()`, like this:

```
$array1 = [1, 2];
$array2 = [3, 4];

$combined = [
    array_column([$array1, $array2], 0),
    array_column([$array1, $array2], 1),
];

print_r($combined);
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

For the more generic case where you have arrays with variable length (although the same length in both arrays), you could use:

```
$combined = array_map(
    fn ($column) => array_column([$array1, $array2], $column),
    array_keys($array1)
);
```

(where we've assumed the keys in `$array1` are the same in `$array2`)

You could even extend this further to more than 2 arrays if you wished.

Comment: thank you! thats exactly what i was looking for. If I may ask, what could I do if both arrays have more than 2 elements, so for example, [1,2,3,4] and [5,6,7,8], would that approach still work? fyi, both arrays will have the same number of elements.

Comment: I added details of a more generic solution, I hope that works for you

Comment: thank you so much kind sir, appreciate it!